# How can we convert old ClarisWorks/Appleworks files to Word/RTF/Plain Text?

Tags: conversion, appleworks

We've got about 20 old ClarisWorks/Appleworks files created in 1995 we'd like to convert to something readable on a PC, such as Word, RTF, or even plain text.

I've tried opening them in Pages, but Pages complains that documents from that version of AppleWorks are unsupported. I've also tried icWord on my Mac but it crashes upon start up: http://www.panergy-software.com/products/icword/features.html

Any other suggestions other than opening the documents in TextEdit and just extracting the raw plain text at the end of the file?

Comment: Where do you live? I'll ship you an old Macintosh Performa 400 from the early 90s to open up the files ;)

Comment: down in Australia

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/libmwaw/ - open source library project, which includes an OSX conversion application.

http://libmwaw.sourceforge.net/convertMWAW.html - website, using the above library, to convert submitted files